# LINQ devuelve registros repetidos

Tags: linq

Tengo una tabla con el mismo ID en dos registros y me devuelve uno solo repetido.
Probé de dos formas y pasa lo mismo.

```
var x = db.SFI_Mix.Where(c => c.ID_Mix == id).Distinct().ToList();
```

y con

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SFI_MIX WHERE ID_MIX = '" + id + "'";           
var x = db.SFI_Mix.SqlQuery(sql).ToList();
```

Si agrego Distinct() me devuelve uno solo.
¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: En principio no deberias tener 2 registros con el mismo Id.

Comment: En realidad la PK es toda la tabla pero el campo ID_Mix se repite

Comment: Bueno el primer ejemplo que pones deberia funcionar incluso sin el metodo .Distinct(). Solo recuerda que Where retorna una coleccion por lo que debes recorrer cada elemento de X para mostrarlo

Comment: Pero no funciona, sin distinct retorna dos registros repetidos, con distinct uno solo.

Comment: Que resultado esperas agregando `Distinct`?  No entiendo bien cual es el problema

Comment: Que no repita un solo registro y devuelva los dos registros diferentes que estan cargados en la BD

Comment: Entonces para que agregas el `.Distinct()`. El Distinct es justamente para no traer registros repetidos, significa que debe devolver registros **distintos** entre sí

Answer (score 2):

La consult sería así:

```
    var x = db.SFI_Mix.Where(c => c.ID_Mix == id).ToList();
```

para recorrela:

```
    foreach(var item in x)
    {
        var idMix = item.ID_Mix;
        /// los datos que quieras ver de cada fila.
    }
```

El Distinct se usa para que solo muestre el primero que cumpla con la condición de comparación.

Si te trae uno solo, es que los registros son idénticos. Con el Foreach vas a poder verificarlo manualmente.

Saludos